# How to check missing value in array of objects and add that missing value with special characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm currently checking the missing values of an array of objects by the object values, and that is working well if I'm using numbers or string numbers. But in some cases, the missing value will be a string number with a special character. I have tried to split the given value and to take the number, and then doing the check if that value is missing, but then I'm stuck in assigning that special character back to the value. This is the code of what I've tried so far

```js
const one = '<0';
const two = '20+';

const data = [
    { key: 1, value: 0 },
  { key: 2, value: 0 },
  { key: 3, value: 0 },
  { key: 7, value: 0 },
  { key: 8, value: 0 },
]

const min = one.split(/([0-9]+)/);
const max = two.split(/([0-9]+)/);

const numbersArr = new Array(+max[1]);
  for (let i = +min[1]; i <= +max[1]; i++) {
    numbersArr[i] = i;
  }
  const missingLabels = numbersArr.filter(
    (itemOne) => !data.some((itemTwo) => itemTwo.key == `${min[0].length>0 && +min[1] === itemOne ? min[0] : ''}${itemOne}${max[2].length>0 && +max[1] === itemOne ? max[2] : ''}`)
  );
 missingLabels.map((item) => {
    data.push({ key: `${min[0].length>0 ? min[0].length : null}${item}`, value: 0 });
  });

console.log(data)
```

and the expected result should be `[{key: '<0', value: 0}, {key: '1', value: 0}, ... {key: '20+', value:0}]`
What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve my problem? Any example will be appreciated!

Comment: Data should be populated with the missing values, including `one` and `two` constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match `min` and `max` and take the data into a hash table for mapping either known keys or add new objects.

For the wanted keys, you could spread an object with the new key.

```js
const
    getValue = v => +v.toString().match(/\d+/)[0],
    one = '<0',
    two = '20+',
    data = [{ key: '<0', value: 0 }, { key: 2, value: 0 }, { key: 3, value: 0 }, { key: 7, value: 0 }, { key: 8, value: 0 }, { key: '20+', value: 0 }],
    min = getValue(one),
    max = getValue(two),
    getKey = k => ({ [min]: one, [max]: two }[k] || k),
    keys = data.reduce((r, o) => (r[getValue(o.key)] = o, r), {}),
    result = Array.from(
        { length: max - min + 1 },
        (_, i) => ({ key: null, value: 99, ...keys[min + i], key: getKey(min + i) })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, but my result should be like this `[{key: '<0', value: 0}, {key: '1', value: 0}, ... {key: '20+', value:0}]`. So the data will include special characters :(

Comment: but it should take the value for zero rsp 20?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If the initial data is missing `<0`, we should add it to it as new object, and also if the initial data is missing `20+` we should add it to it as new object. So the expected result will be `[{key: '<0', value: 0}, {key: '1', value: 0}, {key: '2', value: 0}, ... {key: '20+', value:0}]`

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: if you don't mind the order of the keys, you could shrink the mapping function to `(_, i) => ({ value: 99, ...keys[min + i], key: key(min + i) })`.

Comment: I actually need them to be in ascending order, but thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Sorry I'm bothering you, but what if `data` array has this object `{ key: '20+', value: 25}` and if we do this check, it will override the value of 25 to 99. Any idea how to avoid that? Thanks

Comment: you need to get only a number as key for the hash table. please see edit.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you very much, Nina!